# Handling NoneType when using addition

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Im trying to add some values up but some of the values have a NoneType value.  Now I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866208/python-dealing-with-nonetype-before-cast-addition) but I need some help.  Im hoping someone can explain to me how I can get this to work with django.

Here is my for loop in my views.py:

```
next_il = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year=next_year)
for inv in next_il:
   total_m2 += inv.maturity_amount
```

Now inv.maturity_amount is the value I'm trying to handle that has NoneType.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for inv in next_il:
   total_m2 += inv.maturity_amount or 0
```

And may be you should set `default=0` for `maturity_amount` field.

And it's better to use [DB aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) here:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_m2 = Investment.objects.filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year=next_year).aggregate(Sum('maturity_amount'))
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices that occur to me.

```
next_il = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year=next_year)
for inv in next_il:
   total_m2 += 0 if inv.maturity_amount is None else inv.maturity_amount
```

I actually like this better:

```
next_il = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = plan).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year=next_year)
for inv in next_il:
   try:
       total_m2 += inv.maturity_amount
   except TypeError:
       log.warning( "Null maturity amount" )
```

Comment: This does not throw an exception.  It silences the exception.  What are you saying?

Comment: @Steve: It's better to delete incorrect comments than add apologies.  Just delete your comments.